# Criar menu dentro de um alert() com laço de repetição

Tags: javascript, for, alert

Estou tentando criar um menu de opções para que o usuário escolha um dos 20 exercícios anteriores para abrir no navegador. Só que ao invés de criá-lo manualmente, uso a estrutura de repetição `for` com duas variáveis x e i para criar este menu automaticamente. Mas eu queria colocar este texto gerado pelo laço dentro de uma caixa de diálogo `alert(texto)`. Já tentei de várias formas, mas nenhuma delas deram sucesso.

1º Tentativa

```js
var x;
var i = 38;
for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
  texto = (x+1) + "- Exercício" +(i++)+ "\n";
}
var menu = parseInt(prompt(texto));
```

2º Tentativa

```js
var x; 
var i = 28;
document.write("<div id='menu'>");
for (x = 0; x <= 20; x++) {
  document.write((x+1) + "- Exercício" +(i++)+ "<br>");
}
document.write("</div>");
var texto = document.getElementById('menu');
var alert(texto);
```

3º Tentativa

```js
var x;
var i = 38;
alert("Escolha um exercício para abrir:");
for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
  var menu = parseInt(prompt((x+1) + "- Exercício " +(i++)+ "\n"));
}
```

> *Pergunta:* É possível criar este menu grande dentro de uma caixa de diálogo usando apenas um laço de repetição?
>   *Obs.* Estou apenas começando a montá-lo, e se estiver faltando alguma informação, não desconsidere esta pergunta. :-'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> É possível criar este menu grande dentro de uma caixa de diálogo usando apenas um laço de repetição?

Resposta rápida: **não**.

O `alert` não funciona como uma caixa de seleção. Se você criar um *loop* que chama alertas (`alert`)  ou caixas de diálogo (como o `prompt`), uma será chamada após a outra, veja:

```js
// Note que assim que você fechar uma alerta,
// outra aparecerá logo em seguida, até chegar
// na décima (e final) iteração.
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  alert(`Exercício ${i}`);
}
```

Suponho que o que você precisa criar é uma caixa de seleção:

```js
// Criamos um menu de seleção:
const select = document.createElement('select');

// A cada iteração, adicionamos mais uma
// opção ao menu de seleção (criado acima):
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = i;
  option.textContent = `Exercício ${i}`;
  select.appendChild(option);
}

// Criamos um listener de evento para saber
// quando um exercício for selecionado:
select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(`Exercício selecionado: ${event.target.value}`);
});

// Adicionamos o menu de seleção ao <body>:
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

Se voc quiser algo mais no formato do `alert`, e não um menu de seleção, como demonstrado, sugiro que dê uma olhada em bibliotecas como a [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

### Referência:

- [`Document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement);
- [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild);
- [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener);
- [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/target);
- [`change` (evento)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).